# Structures in C:Why this does not show incompatible type for fied fe;

Tags: c, struct

Could someone please explain first 2 cases given below for structures in c?and how it works?

Case:1

```
struct vertex{
int info;
struct vertex * nextertex;
struct edge *firstEdge;};    //why no error as incompatible type for field firstEdge?
```

This code does not generate error!We do not have struct edge in the whole code!!

Case:2

```
struct vertex{
int info;
struct vertex * nextertex;
struct edge *firstEdge;};    

struct edge{
struct vertex * destVertex;
struct edge *nextEdge;};
```

Same as case:1,difference being we have struct edge after struct vertex definition. No errors!

Case:3

```
struct vertex{
int info;
struct vertex * nextVertex;
struct edge firstEdge;};    

struct edge{
struct vertex * destVertex;
struct edge *nextEdge;};
```

This seems more obvious.Throws error as incompatible type for field firstEdge in struct v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C has a concept of *complete* and *incomplete* types.

C says an incomplete type lacks *sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type*, while a complete type provides
*sufficient information*.

C does not allow you to declare a structure type with a member of an incomplete type but you are allowed to declare a structure type with a member of a type pointer to an incomplete type. In the latter case trying to a dereference the pointer to the incomplete type is not valid if the type has not been *completed* (by declaring the structure type *with its defining content later in the same scope*).

Answer (score 0):

Replacing struct edge firstEdge with struct edge *firstEdge eliminates the error or define edge then vertex.

Answer (score 0):

In the first two cases, you're defining a *pointer* to some structure[`struct edge *`], so the definition  is valid. The definition of `struct edge` need not precede the `struct vertex` definition.

In the third case, you're defining a *variable* of a structure. To do that, the compiler needs to have the definition of that other structure before it is used.